# Checking cells contain data before printing - Run-Time error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I've been doing some work on a spreadsheet for work that I've, up until this point, been able to solve issues for hunting around online. I'm relatively new to VBA and have built most of this from researching online so it may be a pretty rubbish way to do it. Unfortunately I've run into a problem with the following code which is giving me a Type mismatch error (Run-time 13). I suspect the code is pretty self explanatory, however I'm essentially trying to disable printing in the event that certain cells aren't completed. The Run-time error is highlighting the bolded section.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Response As Integer
With Sheets("Settlement Instruction")
    **If .Range("M1").Value = "" Or .Range("P1").Value = "" _
        Or .Range("E2").Value = "" Or .Range("E3").Value = "" Or .Range("E4").Value = "" Or .Range("M4").Value = "" Or .Range("U3").Value = "" _
        Or (.Range("M1").Value = "WA" And .Range("P1").Value = "Settlement" And .Range("T22").Value = "") _
        Or (.Range("P1").Value = "Outsource" And (.Range("C32").Value = "" Or .Range("H37").Value = "" Or .Range("C44").Value = "")) _
        Or (.Range("P1").Value = "Settlement" And (.Range("G6").Value = "" Or .Range("F8").Value = "" Or .Range("N8").Value = "" Or .Range("F9").Value = "" Or .Range("C32").Value = "" Or .Range("Q35").Value = "" Or .Range("Q36").Value = "" Or .Range("H37").Value = "" Or .Range("F41").Value = "" Or .Range("C44").Value = "")) _
        Or (.Range("P1").Value = "Rego Only" Or "Prep Only" And (.Range("F16").Value = "" Or .Range("F41").Value = "" Or .Range("C44").Value = "")) Then**
        Response = MsgBox("Please complete all mandatory fields marked in YELLOW.", vbOK, "Information Required")
        If Response = vbOK Then
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Response = vbCancel Then
            Cancel = True

        End If
    End If
End With
```

Prior to this I had the following code working (aside from some of the checks being incorrect):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Response As Integer
With Sheets("Settlement Instruction")
    If (.Range("M1").Value = "" Or .Range("E2").Value = "" Or .Range("P1").Value = "" Or .Range("E3").Value = "" Or .Range("E4").Value = "" Or .Range("M4").Value = "" Or .Range("U3").Value = "" Or .Range("C32").Value = "" Or (.Range("P1").Value <> "Outsource" And .Range("F41").Value = "" And .Range("Q35").Value = "" And .Range("Q36").Value = "") Or .Range("C44").Value = "" Or .Range("H37").Value = "" Or (.Range("P1").Value = "Settlement" And (.Range("G6").Value = "" Or .Range("F8").Value = "" Or .Range("N8").Value = "" Or .Range("F9").Value = "")) Or (.Range("P1").Value = "Settlement" And .Range("M1").Value = "WA" And .Range("T22") = "")) Then
        Response = MsgBox("Please complete all mandatory fields marke in YELLOW.", vbOK, "Information Required")
        If Response = vbOK Then
            Cancel = True
        ElseIf Response = vbCancel Then
            Cancel = True

        End If
    End If
End With
```

Part of the change was to make the code easier to work with instead of on the same line, however I needed to make some changes to the checks that were completed.
I'm after 1 thing mainly. Is anyone able to see what's causing the Run-time error. I did check the info on Microsoft I think it was (been a couple of days since I looked at it due to time constraints) and the only thing I could deduce was that maybe I was checking values as text rather than integers. I then changed formatting for the only 2 integer fields to text but still had the same issue.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because of this

```
.Range("P1").Value = "Rego Only" Or "Prep Only"
```

You can't use it like that

Change it to

```
.Range("P1").Value = "Rego Only" Or .Range("P1").Value = "Prep Only"
```